# SQL query to retrieve all table's un-unique identifiers (indexes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to count for every table in database, the number of unique and number of un-unique identifiers (indexes)

I am using SQL Server 2012 database

Comment: Which DB Server you're using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN is_unique = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) uniqueIndex, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN is_unique = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) unUniqueIndex
FROM sys.indexes i 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND t.type = 'U'
GROUp BY t.name;
```

Comment: please provide explanation to your answer so that OP and Other user may understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  object_name(object_id), 
         sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  'Primary_Count',
        sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) 'Unique_Count'
from sys.indexes m
group by object_id,is_unique_constraint
```

Sys.Indexes will contain a column type if it is 1 means that is unique , if it is 2 means non unique constraint and if it zero means heap for a particular object_id.

Comment: please provide explanation to your answer so that OP and Other user may understand better

Answer (score 0):

basing the query on sys.tables, gives you all tables in the system, including those without indexes:

```
select 
    tab.name [table name]
    ,sum(case when idx.is_unique = 0 then 1 else 0 end) [unique]
    ,sum(case when idx.is_unique = 1 then 0 else 1 end) [non_unique]
from 
    sys.tables tab
    left join sys.indexes idx
    on idx.object_id = tab.object_id
group by
    tab.name
```